# Import a .dat file in spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I am supposed to access a `.dat` file to perform some code. The directions that I am following are telling me to make a subdirectory for the main code then make another subdirectory for the `.dat` file. However, I am not entirely sure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

So far, everything I have tried has given me the following error message:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: what to you get when you run `Path.cwd()`?

Comment: I get an alert saying that 'Path' is undefined.

Comment: sorry, you have you import it first `from pathlib import Path`